# Input search in react is empty after setState

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a get query if I enter some letters in the search field.
But if I call the setState the input field is always set empty.
Thanks for help.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  isFetching: false,
  user: []

};

this.suche = this.suche.bind(this);
}

async suche(e) {
const name = e.target.value;

const ergebnis = await axios
  .get("http://HOST:PORT/BACKEND/SERVLET?Param1")
  .then(res => {
    const user = res.data;
    this.setState({ user });
  });
}

render() {
return (
  <Col md="4">
    <label
      className="field a-field a-field_a2"
      style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "10%" }}
    >
      <input
        className="field__input a-field__input"
        placeholder="z.B. Hans"
        required
        onChange={this.suche}           
      />
      <span className="a-field__label-wrap">
        <span className="a-field__label">Name</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </Col>
);
}
```

this is my user array

[image]

Comment: You're setting `user` to the state, but display `sucheNach` in the input?

Comment: Oh sorry. I have give it a try. Have edit my question

Comment: You don't set it to anything--why would there be a value in it? Prior you didn't set the `sucheNach` state in your `onChange` handler, so it's going to be empty.

Comment: Are you sure `user` is an array? Can you give an example of the contents of `res.data`? (e.g. by console.logging the response)

Comment: The method you use is not a best practice read this article https://link.medium.com/IQT6BrhU71

Answer (score 0):

`user` holds the list of users that matches the query, so you need an additional state value. Let's call it `query`, then on input change, you update the `query` and on successful API call, you update the `user` list.

```
this.state = {
  isFetching: false,
  user: [],
  query: ""
};

async suche(e) {
const name = e.target.value;
this.setState({ query: name });
const ergebnis = await axios
  .get("http://HOST:PORT/BACKEND/SERVLET?Param1")
  .then(res => {
    const user = res.data;
    this.setState({ user });
  });
}
```

And to display the value entered in the input field:

```
<input
  className="field__input a-field__input"
  placeholder="z.B. Hans"
  required
  onChange={this.suche}
  value={this.state.query}           
/>
```